How do i sync Wordpress databases between staging and production
How do I selectively synchronise wordpress database between staging and production. I cannot simply export (staging) -> modify (url) -> import (prod) as I will lose essential membership data.
For additional context, I have the following setup which overrides my development db with staging db. However, this will not work for the staging to prod due to posibillity of losing data.

